# Who are the so-called "political elite" in Britain?

Tags: united-kingdom, brexit

It is a central axiom of those supporting Brexit that Britain is governed by a "political elite" who are out of touch with the views of ordinary people.

The implication seems to be that people who support Britain's membership of the EU are part of the "elite", and one assumes therefore that those who are in favour of Leave do not consider themselves "elite".

What is the sense of "elite" that makes such people as Yvette Cooper, Vince Cable, Chuka Umunna, Hilary Benn or Tom Watson, more "elite" than Old Etonians like Boris Johnson or Jacob Rees Mogg - or other public school chappies like Nigel Farage.

So who, in Brexit parlance, belongs to the "political elite"?

Comment: According to whom?

Comment: According to people such as Nigel Farage who perpetually assert that Britain is controlled by an out-of-touch elite.

Comment: @WS2 Given Farage has also recently used the term "the Islington, middle-upper class, Champagne socialist Labour party" I suspect you could rapidly dig through enough of his public comments to work out which whistles he's blowing.

Comment: I would say that references to a 'political elite' in Britain *long* predates the issue of Brexit.

Comment: @Time4Tea True. And no reasonable person would deny that there is a "political elite" in Britain - as there is in most countries. However Farage is using the term in a subtly different way.  He does not include himself as one of these political elite - which as another commenter has pointed out is ridiculous. Another thing is that he speaks of this "elite" as though it were a conspiracy across political parties to deceive the broad mass of the electorate to their own advantage - which is equally ridiculous, and a kind of conspiracy theory -a bit like Trump's notion of "inside the beltway".

Answer (score 10):

Anyone except members of the Brexit Party. The name calling is not based on any kind of reason or clear definition, it's just an insult hurled at anyone who opposes the Brexit Party (and before that UKIP).

As you point out, Farage is clearly one of the political elite, enjoying a jet-setting lifestyle, known income deep into six figures and likely even more, rubbing shoulders with Donald Trump, ex-public school Tory, cushy public servant job that he rarely even bothers attending.

So it's clear that when he decries the "political elite", he just means "everyone else".